# substuting cottage cheese for cream cheese in a cheesecake

Tags: cheese

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use cottage cheese instead of cream cheese when making a cheesecake?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16693/can-i-use-cottage-cheese-instead-of-cream-cheese-when-making-a-cheesecake)

Can I use cottage cheese and ricotta cheese together for a cheesecake which needs to be baked. I bought cottage cheese instead of cream cheese for a recipe, can I substitute?

Comment: How attached are you to your existing recipe? Do you have enough ricotta to simply make a ricotta cheesecake? There are also cottage cheese cheesecakes, though I've not personally tried them.

Comment: I'll note that if what you really like about cheesecake is the smooth, dense texture, then nothing other than cream cheese will do. You can make a cake out of all sorts of other types of cheese, but they won't be *cheesecake*. (If all I had was cottage cheese and ricotta, I'd acquire or make some egg noodles and make kugel. Much better use of the ingredients.)