# Can I use yogurt cheese in cheesecake by substituting the cream cheese?

Tags: baking, substitutions, cheese, cheesecake, cream-cheese

It is very hard to find cream cheese or mascarpone where I live in India, so I just wanted to know whether I can make a cheesecake with yogurt cheese or not?

Comment: you might also find this [question's answers](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16693/can-i-use-cottage-cheese-instead-of-cream-cheese-when-making-a-cheesecake) usefull

Answer (score 6):

I hope I am not making a wrong assumption here. But German quark is a soft cheese with somewhat creamy consistency which is made from a yogurt variety (or at least a cultured milk variety) .

If "yoghurt cheese" is similar to quark in the way I think it is, you are probably better off not making a substitution, but use a recipe which was made for quark (or topfen, which is the Austrian word for the same cheese). They will probably give you a better result than a substitution. The search term to use would be Käsekuchen, this is the German version of cheesecake, and it is traditionally made with quark. If you cannot decipher a German recipe, I noticed that Google returns some results for "Käsekuchen recipe", you can specify results in English in the advanced search options if needed.

Comment: I'm thinking he probably means paneer...

Comment: Yogurt cheese is what you get when you strain yogurt in cheesecloth, essentially draining the yogurt whey.

Comment: @Aaronut No, paneer is a different thing

Answer (score 1):

You are likely to get a somewhat different outcome, as the yogurt cheese probably will likely contain more moisture, and have a less smooth texture than the traditional cheese used in cheesecake.

This is not to say that your outcome won't be delicious, but it won't be the same.

There are cheesecake recipes that are based on ricotta that might be a closer match to yogurt cheese.  You might wish to [google some of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=rictotta%20cheesecake).